# Custom attributes in emailtemplate give error after checkout

Tags: magento, custom-attributes, magento-1.6

I have a problem when I checkout with a payment provider. 
Pay after goed ok..

I get the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   /usr/home/somename/domains/url.nl/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
>   on line 29

On line 29:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId()); ?>
```

I need to show these 3 custom attributes.

```
Verpakking: <?php echo $_product->getVerpakking(); ?><br>
EAN: <?php echo $_product->getEancodeeenheid(); ?><br>
Z-index: <?php echo $_product->getZindexnummer(); ?>
```

**I probably need an other way to show the custom attributes into the New Order email template.**

Does anyone knows how I can show the custom attributes without the Mage getModel?

The .phtml file:

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder(); ?>
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId()); ?> 
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <strong><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></strong><br>
        Verpakking: <?php echo $_product->getVerpakking(); ?><br>
        EAN: <?php echo $_product->getEancodeeenheid(); ?><br>
        Z-index: <?php echo $_product->getZindexnummer(); ?>
        <?php if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the following part:

> $_item->getProduct()->getId()

Check how the $_item is populated and add this to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. (how it's populated?) Do I need to show more code of that file to see whats going on?

Comment: Yes... Somewhere before the supplied code-line, there should be a line which defines $_item. I think it'll be an orderItem. Than you should add the custom attributes to the orderitems and possibly the quoteitems because the product could be deleted after an order has been created.

Comment: I have added the code in the post, how to add the custom attributes to the orderitems :Z

Comment: try doing $_item->getProductId()

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductId() on a non-object in... 

I tried <?php $_item->getProductId() ?> and <?php $_item->getProductId(); ?>

:(

Comment: any other ideas?, I really need to show these attributes in the emailtemplate.

Comment: It's very strange that the $_item is not available on that page... There should be an orderitem when you are trying to print it...

Comment: When I checkout without using the payment provider there are no problems. I'm stuck with this, dunno what to do. These are moments I really hate Magento, it doesn't make sence